# Writing a modelmapper converter for an enum which is part of a nested list

Tags: java, modelmapper

I'm unable to correctly map a string to an enum.

Please consider the following code:

```
enum AddressType {
    SENDER("Sender"),
    RECEIVER("Receiver"),

    public static AddressType valueOfString(String label) {
        switch (label) {
            case "Sender":
                return SENDER;
            case "Receiver":
                return RECEIVER;
        }
        return null;
    }
}


class Address {
    
    private String addressType;

}


class Shipment {
    
    private List<Address> addresses;
}


class CreateShipmentRequest {
    
    private List<Shipment> shipments;
}

class AddressDTO {

    private AddressType addressType;
    
}

public class ShipmentDTO {
 
    private List<AddressDTO> addresses = new ArrayList<>();
    
}

public class ShipmentRequestDTO {

    private List<ShipmentDTO> shipments = new ArrayList<>();

}

Converter<String, AddressType> addressTypeConverter = ctx -> ctx.getSource() == null ? null : AddressType.valueOfString(ctx.getSource());

modelMapper = new ModelMapper();
    PropertyMap<CreateShipmentRequest, ShipmentRequestDTO> requestRequestDTOPropertyMap = new PropertyMap<>() {
        @Override
        protected void configure() {
            
            // THIS IS APPARENTLY WRONG
            using(addressTypeConverter).map(source.getShipments().get(0).getAddresses().get(0).getAddressType(),
                    destination.getShipments().get(0).getAddresses().get(0).getAddressType());

        }
    };          
    
modelMapper.addMappings(requestRequestDTOPropertyMap);
```

Apparently the line `...map(source..., destination...)` is wrong.